# regex question for removal of javascript malware

Tags: windows, regex, malware

Been hit with some nasty javascript malware on my site.  I know that each offending code block starts with the following:

```
<script language=javascript><!-- 
(function()
```

and ends with

```
</script>
```

I'd like to remove the nasty bits via regex on windows, using some sort of freeware regex replacement tool. Any suggestions here? Thank You much.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/), it has a built-in regular expression search/replace that works well. Also I believe the demo works for 30 days.

If you just want to remove *all* Javascript blocks from your pages, you would search for:

`<script language=javascript><!--[\s\S\p]+</script>`

`(\s = whitespace, \S = non-whitespace, \p = newline characters)`

Make sure you have the regular expressions box checked in the search/replace dialog.

**Edit**

Add to the regular expression that after `<script>` should follow `<!--` (I altered the above example) and you'll get only those `<script>` sections that include a comment immediately following the opening tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to only remove the code block that has the opening comment with the function, not all script blocks.

Comment: Edited example to match what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use configure Privoxy (http://privoxy.org). It uses the PCRE library and is available for Windows. In order to filter you should do the following:

1. In the Privoxy configuration directory add

   ```
   FILTER: my-js-purger
   s@<script\s+language=javascript><!--\s+(function().*?</script>@@s
   ```

   to `user.filter` file,
2. Add

   ```
   { +filter{my-js-purger} }
   /
   ```

   to `user.action` file (replace `/` with the names of sites you want to apply filter to, or leave it as is if you want to apply it to all sites).
3. Ensure that there are uncommented lines

   ```
   listen-address 127.0.0.1:8118
   actionsfile user.action
   filterfile user.filter
   ```

   in `config` file (I believe it is safe to just add them at the end of `config` file regardless whether they already exist).
4. Start privoxy.
5. Configure your browser to use `127.0.0.1:8118` as a http/https proxy server.